# Regex to split text file in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a way to parse a string of a transcript into speaker segments (as a list). Speaker labels are denoted by the upper-casing of the speaker's name followed by a colon. The problem I am having is some names have a number of non upper-case characters. Examples might include the following:

OBAMA: said something

O'MALLEY: said something else

GOV. HICKENLOOPER: said something else entirely'

I have written the following regex, but I am struggling to get it to work:

```
mystring = "OBAMA: said something \nO'MALLEY: said something else \nGOV. HICKENLOOPER: said something else entirely"

parse_turns = re.split(r'\n(?=[A-Z]+(\ |\.|\'|\d)*[A-Z]*:)', mystring)
```

What I think I have written (and ideally what I want to do) is a command to split the string based on:

**1.** Find a newline

**2.** Use positive look-ahead for one or more uppercase characters

**3.** If upper-case characters are found look for optional characters from the list of periods, apostrophes, single spaces, and digits

**4.** If these optional characters are found, look for additional uppercase characters.

**5.** Crucially, find a colon symbol at the end of this sequence.

**EDIT:** In many cases, the content of the speech will have newline characters contained within it, and possibly colon symbols. As such, the only thing separating the speaker label from the content of speech is the sequence mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you match the whole line instead of split? `^[A-Z]+(?:[ .'\d]+[A-Z]+)*:.*$` https://regex101.com/r/m5a8Ov/1

Comment: What do you mean by `but I am struggling to get it to work` https://ideone.com/njYorK

Comment: It will split the string where I want it to, but also includes additional splits. Specifically, I get a list that contains the turns, in addition to an empty string, and a string with just an apostrophe

Comment: And if you try it like this? https://ideone.com/lao461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change (\ |.|\'|\d) to [\ .\'\d] or (?:\ |.|\'|\d)

```
import re

mystring = "OBAMA: said something \nO'MALLEY: said something else \nGOV. HICKENLOOPER: said something else entirely"

parse_turns = re.split(r'\n(?=[A-Z]+[\ \.\'\d]*[A-Z]*:)', mystring)
print(parse_turns)
```

Comment: How infuriatingly simple! Thanks, that's done the job perfectly! :)

Comment: The character class can be shortened to `[ .\'\d]` without the `|` You changed the capturing group to a non character class so that split does not keep the capturing group right? As in both examples https://ideone.com/njYorK and https://ideone.com/lao461

Answer (score 1):

If it's true that the speaker's name and what they said are separated by a colon, then it might be simpler to move away from regex to do your splitting.

```
list_of_things = []
mystring = "OBAMA: Hi\nO'MALLEY: True Dat\nHUCK FINN: Sure thing\n"
lines = mystring.split("\n")# 1st split the string into lines based on the \n character
for line in lines:
    colon_pos = line.find(":",0)  # Finds the position of the first colon in the line
    speaker, utterance = line[0:colon_pos].strip(), line[colon_pos+1:].strip()
    list_of_things.append((speaker, utterance))
```

At the end, you should have a neat list of tuples containing speakers, and the things they said.

Comment: Thanks. The main problem with this approach is that in many cases there will be a colon contained within the things they have said, that may also be on their own distinct line. So, if for instance, we have as part of the string: HUCK FINN: Sure thing\n it's now 6:30pm",  it will split on the colon contained within the time reference

Comment: Yeah, that's fine - this loop only cares about the initial colon, so should work as long as there are no speakers with weird punctuation in their names. In your example though, I see there are extra new-line characters, so splitting on a single line break character might cause an issue.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out.